# Setting custom subdomain on Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I want to set a custom subdomain to a Heroku application. The top-level domain is associated to a different application outside Heroku.

I've read Heroku's [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) documentation, but I'm still unclear on how to approach this.

From the documentation, it gives off the impression that I must set the top-level domain to the application if I want to set the custom subdomain. Is this the case?

At the moment I've set a CNAME record pointing to the Heroku app in question:

```
subdomain.domain.com => subdomain.herokuapp.com
```

Is this sufficient? Or would I also need to set the top-level domain? If so, would it conflict with it's association to the different application?

Just want to make sure I'm setting it correctly, since the DNS propagation takes a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine. You only need to set the top-level domain to the app if you want the top-level domain to resolve to the app.